# ¿Cómo actualizar aplicación ClickOnce?

Tags: .net, clickonce, deployment

Tengo una aplicación .NET que distribuyo utilizando `ClickOnce` disponible sólo en línea (*online only*). ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se descargue nuevamente (que no tome la caché)?

¿Hay alguna forma de lograrlo sin hacer un deploy de una versión más nueva?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te dejo algunas opciones:

Puedes utilizar [Mage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.80).aspx) de esta forma en la linea de comandos (si no tienes Visual studio Instalado en esa pc debes tener al menos *Windows SDK* o *Framework SDK*):

```
mage -cc
```

Si no tienes Mage instalado, Otra opción es ejecutar esto en la línea de comandos:

```
rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
```

También puedes borrar la carpeta donde se instalan los [clickonce](/questions/tagged/clickonce) (probado en maquinas con *windows 7* o superior):

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Apps
```

**Esto deberías hacerlo como último recurso ya que borrarías todas las aplicaciones [clickonce](/questions/tagged/clickonce) instaladas.**

Comment: Podria sugerir que el texto `Esto deberías hacerlo como último recurso ya que borrarías todas las aplicaciones clickonce instaladas.` vaya en negritas, ya que algun lector podria realizar el procedimiento sin leer esa parte

Comment: Listo ! Gracias @jasilva

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos opciones:

1. Eliminar el directorio de trabajo de `clickonce`, podrías crearte
   un `.bat` con la siguiente instrucción para usarlo siempre que lo
   necesites:

   rd /s /q "%homedrive%%homepath%\Config~1\Apps\2.0"
2. Subir la versión de la aplicación.

Comment: fijate que en la pregunta aclara que como hacerlo sin aumentar la versión.